# New black keyboard on IOS 5

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have seen a black keyboard on some applications like this one, but i can't find how to do it.

[screenshot http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/2037/photo141011155315.png](http://img708.imageshack.us/img708/2037/photo141011155315.png)

any idea?

Comment: This might have been done by Ui skinning, which would mean that you have to do it yourself for your app.

Answer (score 5):

I don’t think that’s new. Check out the `keyboardAppearance` property on the UITextInputTraits protocol, which both UITextField and UITextView implement: if you set it to `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert`, you get that same (or a very similar) black-bordered keyboard.

Comment: This will work, just make sure to animate a black UIView behind it to cover up the transparency.

Comment: I don't know how to do it. Can you write some code? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

try this:

```
[myTextField setKeyboardAppearance:UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert];
```

Where "myTextField" is your text field or textView.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

As of iOS 7, `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert` got deprecated, but there is `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark`, which should do the same.

To support both iOS 7 and iOS 6, you can use:

```
mytextfield.keyboardAppearance = (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0") ? UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert : UIKeyboardAppearanceDark);
```